# How to define a static AlignedVec buffer for deserializing rkyv within Tokio task

Tags: rust, deserialization, rust-tokio

Using [rkyv_codex](https://github.com/zyansheep/rkyv_codec), I try to read Archived rkyv objects from a TCP stream within a Tokio tasks. However, since Tokio imposes that the lifetime of all references inside the task are 'static, I keep getting compile errors.

Let's say I have the following function:

```
use rkyv::validation::validators::DefaultValidator;
use rkyv::{AlignedVec, Archive};
use rkyv_codec::{archive_stream, VarintLength};
use tokio::net::TcpStream;

async fn test<N, B>(mut stream: TcpStream)
where
    N: Archive<Archived = B> + 'static,
    B: bytecheck::CheckBytes<DefaultValidator<'static>> + 'static,
{
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        let mut buffer = AlignedVec::new();
        let data = archive_stream::<_, N, B, VarintLength>(&mut stream, &mut buffer)
            .await
            .unwrap();
    });
}
```

where the `archive_stream` function has the following signature:

```
pub async fn archive_stream<'b, Inner: AsyncRead + Unpin, N, B, L: LengthCodec>(
    inner: &mut Inner,
    buffer: &'b mut AlignedVec,
) -> Result<&'b Archived<N>, RkyvCodecError>
where
    N: rkyv::Archive<Archived = B> + 'b,
    B: bytecheck::CheckBytes<DefaultValidator<'b>> + 'b,
{...}
```

The compiler now throws an error when passing `buffer` to the `archive_stream`  function saying that `argument requires that 'buffer' is borrowed for 'static`.

```
error[E0597]: `buffer` does not live long enough
  --> pkg/net/events/src/service/test.rs:13:73
   |
13 |         let data = archive_stream::<_, N, B, VarintLength>(&mut stream, &mut buffer)
   |                    -----------------------------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                    |                                                    |
   |                    |                                                    borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                    argument requires that `buffer` is borrowed for `'static`
...
16 |     });
   |     - `buffer` dropped here while still borrowed
```

I understand that the buffer has to be static because it has to have the same lifetime as types `N` and `B`. Those have to be static because they are used within the task. Although it doesn't feel very right, how could I create a static buffer to solve this issue?

Comment: Please always show the full error from `cargo check`.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @ChayimFriedman. I added the full cargo check output in the description.